# Why are HashBytes different

Tags: sql-server

When executing that query:

```
SELECT HashBytes('MD5', CONCAT('A',convert(nvarchar,100),'1234')) as mycol ...
```

I get HashBytes represented such as

```
0xA6A0D....
```

When I do not convert, the HashBytes look like the following:

```
SELECT HashBytes('MD5', CONCAT('A','100','1234')) as mycol

0x88230...
```

Why is it different?

Comment: `N'313'` and `'313'` aren't the same value, and therefore, neither are `N'AVS313@310001'` and `'AVS313@310001'` and so you get different hash values. Data typing is important.

Comment: NCHAR/NVARCHAR are string data encoded as UNICODE and must be valued by the N prefix in string values. N for NATIONAL (the NATIONAL language of a specfic country). Strings without N prefix are ASCII encoded. N strings cost 2 bytes per char, while ASCII only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Larnu in the comments, data types matter. To see why you're getting different hashes lets take a look at what `CONCAT` outputs for the two cases:

```sql
SELECT CAST(CONCAT('A',convert(nvarchar,100),'1234') AS VARBINARY(MAX));
```

|  |
| --- |
| 0x41003100300030003100320033003400 |

```sql
SELECT CAST(CONCAT('A','100','1234') AS VARBINARY(MAX));
```

|  |
| --- |
| 0x4131303031323334 |

Because one of the parameters to `CONCAT` is of type `nvarchar` the others are coerced to `nvarchar` as well to return an `nvarchar` result.

Read through the **Remarks** section of the [CONCAT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql#remarks) documentation for a complete accounting of the expected output types for given input types.